# Shockwave and PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, codec, shockwave

I tried finding information on the web, but could not, so I was wondering if anyone has some information:

1. We have made a Flash animation
2. We have embedded it in a PowerPoint slide
3. Everything is working on our side

I just want to make sure before I send it to the client that it will work if someone has no Shockwave plugin installed? In other words, does PowerPoint include the "Codec" to view the item when the PowerPoint file is generated?

I tried uninstalling my Shockwave, but for some reason I am unable to, so I am not sure how to test this.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Kobus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the playback computer doesn't have the correct plug-in, it won't be able to play the Flash animation.  Flash playback doesn't use CODECs in the same sense that WMVs and other movie formats do.

Comment: Thank you, @SteveRindsberg. I have decided to convert the animation into a gif file for the purpose. That seemed counterproductive, but it works :-)